# Leap year code - how to call in the main method?

Tags: java

This is the code I'm using to figure out if a year is a leap year or not:

```
public class leap_year {
public static void main(String args[])
{
  isLeapYear(2009)
}

    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
      if (year % 4 != 0) {
        return false;
      } else if (year % 400 == 0) {
        return true;
      } else if (year % 100 == 0) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
}
```

But when I run the code nothings shows up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not printing anything...

Comment: Yeah I'm confused how I can refer back to the static method somehow. What would I need to print?

Comment: @jjj: You'd print whatever you want to print.  What do you *want* the program to output?

Comment: whether it is a leap year so true or false.

Comment: As Tunaki is saying, you are not doing anything with the return value, you are just calling the method.

Comment: I don't understand these down-votes. Programming is confusing in the beggining, so friendliness would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing prints out, because you haven't ordered it! Use `System.out.println(...)` to print the output out to the console.

Your code should look like this:

```
boolean bool = isLeapYear(2009);
System.out.println(bool);
```

Or print it out directly without using any variable:

```
System.out.println(isLeapYear(2009));
```

Comment: Ohh so I would need to declare it as a boolean first. I understand thanks. I thought about printing isleapyear but was wondering how. thanks

Comment: Welcome, glad you understand it :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working perfectly, you just need to print the result of the method somewhere...

use `System.out.println` and your method as parameter....

```
System.out.println(isLeapYear(2009));
System.out.println(isLeapYear(2016));
```

[image]